# Designing a multi-module project

Tags: java, scala, refactoring, multi-module

I'm new to this concept so I might be wrong in calling it a "multi-module project". In the software I'm making, there's one distinct unit with distinct inputs and outputs. I decided to pull it out and run it as a separate (web) service since it has other values in this stand-alone mode.

But the thing is, now the application which was previously blended with this unit has to run standalone, too. And that means there should be a new way for it to communicate with that unit by calling it's service endpoints which adds new layers of complexity (serializing and de-serializing not-so-simple data into XML and JSON). Is there a common practice for this in software engineering? Can I transmit the data in any other way?

The software is being written in Scala which runs on JVM and may or may not affect this story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't have your original client ap connect to a server, then I would recommend the following module breakdown:

- Service module with Java/Scala API
- Web service module which wraps the service module with Rest/XML/JSON
- Client module which calls directly to the Java/Scala API module

Comment: It sounds good, now what would be best in terms of elegancy in build? Would I need to build the server every time I build the client (is this called a multi-module build?) Or I just jar it and add it as a dependency to client app? Thanks.

Comment: Each module will produce its own artifact - a jar file, or maybe a war file or an ear file for the web service module. The second and third modules would depend on the first, i.e., would include the first jar in their compile-time and run-time classpaths. Build tools such as Maven will provide support for developing multi-module projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can't offer anything on the Scala front, but as far as Java goes you should think of your new service as being in the Service layer of your application, whereas the REST/SOAP/Whatever interface to your service is defined in the Web/Servlet layer.

So let us say you have a service like the following in your com.myco.services package:

```
public interface PersonService {
    public Person createPerson(PersonIdentifier id, PersonType type);
    public Person retrievePerson(PersonIdentifier id);
    public void updatePerson(Person existingPerson);
    public void deletePerson(Person existingPerson);
    public boolean authenticatePerson(String personName, String password);
}
```

We'll take it as read that you have an PersonServiceImpl implementation of this that updates your database or whatever. In your application on the same JVM you can inject the PersonServiceImpl into your code and call the methods directly, without having to marshal or unmarshal the parameters.

In the Web layer you can have a separate PersonServiceController that is mapped to URLs in your servlet. When a URL like "http://myco.com/person/update" is hit, the body of the request can be passed to the controller like so:

```
public class PersonServiceController {
    private final PersonService personService; // Inject PersonServiceImpl in constructor
    ...

    public void updatePerson(String requestBody) {
        Person updatedPerson = unmarshalPerson(requestBody);
        this.personService.updatePerson(updatedPerson);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's pretty much what people do with XML and JSON, what the goal of SOA is, what SOAP was created for, plus things like JMS, etc.